# PHP on OpenShift: How to enable errors and warnings?

Tags: php, openshift

I have moved my app to OpenShift and now, for convenience of getting it actually work, I'd like to enable in-page errors and warnings. Currently, I see a blank page.

How can I enable errors?

In PHP, it's in `php.ini`

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the IRC channel #openshift, I was told that this is not currently not configurable

> (05:06:58 PM) pmorie: ozizka-ntb: it looks like it's provided by the cart - i don't believe you can substitute your own

and I need to use both

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Fun chatting with you today, Ondra.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to set APPLICATION_ENV to development.

> $ rhc env set APPLICATION_ENV=development

According to https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-getting-started.html,

> In development mode, your application will:
>
> 1. Show more detailed errors in browser
> 2. Display startup errors
> 3. Enable the Xdebug PECL extension
> 4. Enable APC stat check
> 5. Ignore your composer.lock file (if applicable)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access `php.ini` then write this on top of your `php` page:

```
<?php
error_reporting(22527);
?>
```

This displays all errors and warnings in the page.

Comment: Well, that was the core of my question - whether I can configure this on OpenShift, externally, not in the code.