# Enable Errors in Openshift PHP

Tags: php, openshift, openshift-php-cartidges

I tried to enable errors in PHP in openshift Cartridge , I was using openshift for past 4 months, everything goes well and with `new Cartridge` I cant able to `enable errors to browser window`

The code i used was

```
<?php
echo "Hello WOrld!";
echo "Hello world!;       //without ending quotes for error
?>
```

And the error i got by

**tail -f /var/lib/openshift/54e9a8d74382ecd2be000161/app-root/php.log**

```
[Wed Mar 11 12:42:31 2015] [error] [client 127.3.126.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) in /var/lib/openshift/54e9a8d74382ecd2be000161/app-root/runtime/repo/index.php on line 5
163.47.13.83 - - [11/Mar/2015:12:42:31 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
```

But in browser window it shows empty page ...

I having this issues for past 3 weeks , I tried lot of workarounds in the below links and nothing worked out

1. [PHP errors NOT being displayed in the browser [Ubuntu 10.10]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050426/php-errors-not-being-displayed-in-the-browser-ubuntu-10-10)
2. [PHP on OpenShift: How to enable errors and warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582409/php-on-openshift-how-to-enable-errors-and-warnings)
3. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1593123

**Note :** After doing the changes in 
**/var/lib/openshift/54e9a8d74382ecd2be000161/php/configuration/etc/php.ini** and I restarted the application from the front end , ie the browser restart option, but nothing works.

**Help me to fix this issue ...**

Answer (score 0):

(For anyone still interested)

Use the debug environment:

```
rhc env set APPLICATION_ENV=development
```

This will, [according to the documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-getting-started.html#other):

- **Show more detailed errors in browser**
- Display startup errors
- Enable the Xdebug PECL extension
- Enable APC stat check
- Ignore your composer.lock file (if applicable)